# how to show the sku of product with out of stock error message in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am trying work on multi bundle products but when trying to add to cart the product is showing out of stock.
I want to show the sku of the product with which the error is created so that I can get the idea of the related product from bundle options
[check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWxVM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From cart, you can get all available products. From there you can check each product and add an error message if the product is currently out of stock.